# type check using conditional statement? JS

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Problem. 
i need to apply condition if number is a NUMBER or STRING or BOOLEAN. I am able to check its type but cant apply condition. why?

```
var g = 5e-2;
alert(typeof g);
if(g === number) //not working
if(g == number) //also not working
alert("yeah it worked");
```

both if are for reference NOT nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**typeof** return `string`  [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

so write

```
 if( typeof g === "number")

 if( typeof g === "string" )
```

Answer (score 0):

`number` is not defined. Did you mean this?

```
if( typeof g === "number")
```

Comment: i wasnt using (typeof g === "number") instead i was using g === number